# aws access key id and secret access key

Tags: amazon-web-services

I tried to understand access keys. I read https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys and says use access keys to sign programmatic requests that you make to AWS.

Can I say `access key id` is like public key and it can be shared, and `secret access key` is like private key that is not sharable? When I connect to AWS in CLI, I need to specify both in `~/.aws/credentials` and I wonder why

Answer (score 5):

Although the internal relation between the two keys is not readily disclosed by aws, I will explain what I gather from their resources and by experience. 
Their REST Api requires an Authorization Header which consists of Access Key ID concatenated with a Signature derived from the secret key. This signature is an HMAC string using the Secret Key and the Message as given here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader. I would imagine the same method being used when we use aws cli.

There are other resources that claim, the access key is essentially public as it can be accessed by others in certain situations as given here: https://alestic.com/2009/11/ec2-credentials/. 
I would imagine that would imply footprint in logs or visibility to admins for individual access keys of users but not their secret keys. The secret key is only shown at the time of creation and thereafter access to it is denied even to an admin.

Comment: *"I would imagine the same method being used when we use aws cli."*  Yes -- you can observe this with the `--debug` option.  Also true of the SDKs.  They all use exactly the same logic.  The access key is public/non-secret, somewhat like a username and the secret key is private/secret, somewhat like a password... but unlike a password, you never send the actual secret key, you use it to generate signatures.  The two values have no apparent mathematical relationship -- they are just a pair of values that are always used together.